# How do I automatically update cells to match values from another sheet when one cell is changed using data validation?

Tags: excel

I have a list of items on Sheet 1 with the names of each item in column A and then further information in the subsequent 5 columns.

On Sheet 2, in each of the cells of column A, I have set it so that I can pick any item from a dropdown list using data validation. I want the subsequent cells in the row to automatically assume the value of the respective cells in Sheet 1.

So if in Sheet 2, Cell A1 I select Item 3 (which is in Cell A3 on Sheet one), I want Cell B1 on Sheet 2 to have the same value as Cell B3 on Sheet 1.

I could get the result I wanted by using =IF($A3='Sheet1'!A3,'Sheet1'!B3,) and then adding each possible item but that seems really long winded and would require adding to the formula every time I added an item.

Any idea if there is a way of doing this? Sorry if my explanation is a bit confusing. My excel knowledge is not great!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Vlookup function
Next to your data validation cell, enter (assuming the first sheet called Sheet1):

```
=Vlookup(a1,Sheet1!a:f,2,0)
```

This will return the data that match for the 2nd column. For the 3rd use:

```
 =Vlookup(a1,Sheet1!a:f,3,0)
```

And so on..